# duplicate record on sql left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

When I use this sql query, There is no duplicate **shops.id**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   shops 
LEFT JOIN expiration 
       ON shops.id = expiration.shopid 
ORDER  BY shops.id
```

But when I use this one (with where statement)  there are many duplicate **shops.id**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   shops 
LEFT JOIN expiration 
       ON shops.id = expiration.shopid 
WHERE  shops.ref = 9 
ORDER  BY shops.id
```

Why **left join** returns duplicate rows and how adding **where** cause this?

Comment: Add some sample table data and show us the two different results. (Formatted text please, not images.)

Comment: I am guessing that you just don't see the duplicates returned by the first query.

Comment: in the first query, put an order by on shops.ref. You will now also see your duplicate record. You just looked over it, it was there

Comment: @GuidoG Sorry. Yes there are duplicate rows at first statement too when I checked order by shops.ref. But why left join returns duplicate rows?

Comment: Because left join try to match each element with another, if you have 1 in one side and two in the other you will have 2, if have 2 and 2, you will have 4.  2 and 4 you will have 8 and so on

Comment: The reason you get duplicates at all, is most likely that you have shops with multiple records in expiration (multiple expiration records with the same shopid).

Comment: Because when you join a master with a detail table, than you get the master as many times as there are details for it. That is how joins work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like every one agree you already have duplicates on your first query but you just missed. Is easy to test

```
 SELECT 'shops', shops.id, COUNT(*)
 FROM shops
 GROUP BY shops.id
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

 UNION ALL      

 SELECT 'expiration ', expiration.shopid , COUNT(*)
 FROM expiration 
 GROUP BY expiration.shopid 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestion how should I get unique rows other than left join?

Comment: `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` But depend on your requirements. Post some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try Select Distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM   shops 
LEFT JOIN expiration 
       ON shops.id = expiration.shopid 
WHERE  shops.ref = 9 
ORDER  BY shops.id
```

Its difficult without the data. but that might help.

Another option might be to include left outer join as well:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM   shops 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN expiration 
           ON shops.id = expiration.shopid 
    WHERE  shops.ref = 9 
    ORDER  BY shops.id
```

Hope it helps.